# A readOnly Equivalent for HTML Select Elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

Is there an attribute or technique for HTML select fields that's equivalent to  `readOnly="true"` for HTML inputs?

I have an form select field I'd like to disable, but still pass on when the form is posted.  If this were an HTML input, I'd do something like this

```
$('select_id').setAttribute('readOnly', 'true');
```

and the browser would render the field as un-editable, but it's value would still be passed to the backend.  I'd like something similar for an HTML select, but doing the following

```
$('#select_id').setAttribute('readOnly', 'true');
```

doesn't work.  The attribute is successfully added to the DOM, but the browser still renders it as selectable.

I realize I could do the following

```
$('#input_id').disabled();
```

but when a field is *disabled* its value isn't passed through to the backend.

I'd like a way to disable this select field but still pass in on to the backend.

(examples use Prototype JS, but I'm interested in any general solution)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Disable all but the selected option:

​

```
<select>
<option disabled="disabled">1</option>
<option selected="selected">2</option>
<option disabled="disabled">3</option>
</select>
```

This way the dropdown still works (and submits its value) but the user can not select another value.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted or why, this appears to work (at least in Chrome, testing other browsers right now)

Comment: @AlanStorm, that is a hell of a test :))

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that user still can deselect options using CTRL+click

Answer (score 3):

add disabled class:

```
.disabled{
   color: grey;
}
```

if class present use prevent default on focus and on click, and dbl click:

```
$('#el').bind('click dblclick focus').function(event){
   if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Worth noting for future googlers, this example appears to be using jQuery.